# Egress traffic from GKE Pod through VPN

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpn

I have a VPC network with a subnet in the range 10.100.0.0/16, in which the nodes reside. There is a route and firewall rules applied to the range 10.180.102.0/23, which routes and allows traffic going to/coming from a VPN tunnel.

If I deploy a node in the 10.100.0.0/16 range, I can ping my devices in the 10.180.102.0/23 range. However, the pod running inside that node cannot ping the devices in the 10.180.102.0/23 range. I assume it has to do with the fact that the pods live in a different IP range(10.12.0.0/14).

How can I configure my networking so that I can ping/communicate with the devices living in the 10.180.102.0/23 range?

Comment: What is your cluster configuration? Did you have activate the option `--enable-ip-alias`? What is your `--cluster-ipv4-cidr` param? Did you have activate secondary IP range? If so, with which values?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have configured the cluster and node pool through the GCP console, not through gcloud, but running `gcloud container clusters describe <cluster>`, gives me that the `clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.12.0.0/14`  and `ipAllocationPolicy:
  clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.12.0.0/14
  clusterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.12.0.0/14
  clusterSecondaryRangeName: gke-XXX-stack-cluster-pods-f28f6de4
  servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.142.0.0/20
  servicesIpv4CidrBlock: 10.142.0.0/20
  servicesSecondaryRangeName: gke-XXX-stack-cluster-services-f28f6de4
  useIpAliases: true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't quite remember exactly how to solve, but I'm posting what I have to help @tdensmore.

You have to edit the ip-masq-agent(which is an agent running on GKE that masquerades the IPs) and this configuration is responsible for letting the pods inside the nodes, reach other parts of the GCP VPC Network, more specifically the VPN. So, it allows pods to communicate with the devices that are accessible through the VPN.

First of all we're gonna be working inside the `kube-system` namespace, and we're gonna put the configmap that configures our ip-masq-agent, put this in a `config` file:

```
nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
  - 10.12.0.0/14  # The IPv4 CIDR the cluster is using for Pods (required)
  - 10.100.0.0/16 # The IPv4 CIDR of the subnetwork the cluster is using for Nodes (optional, works without but I guess its better with it)
masqLinkLocal: false
resyncInterval: 60s
```

and run `kubectl create configmap ip-masq-agent --from-file config --namespace kube-system`

afterwards, configure the ip-masq-agent, put this in a `ip-masq-agent.yml` file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ip-masq-agent
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: ip-masq-agent
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: ip-masq-agent
        image: gcr.io/google-containers/ip-masq-agent-amd64:v2.4.1
        args:
            - --masq-chain=IP-MASQ
            # To non-masquerade reserved IP ranges by default, uncomment the line below.
            # - --nomasq-all-reserved-ranges
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: /etc/config
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            # Note this ConfigMap must be created in the same namespace as the daemon pods - this spec uses kube-system
            name: ip-masq-agent
            optional: true
            items:
              # The daemon looks for its config in a YAML file at /etc/config/ip-masq-agent
              - key: config
                path: ip-masq-agent
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        operator: Exists
      - effect: NoExecute
        operator: Exists
      - key: "CriticalAddonsOnly"
        operator: "Exists"
```

and run `kubectl -n kube-system apply -f ip-masq-agent.yml`

Note: this has been a long time since I've done this, there are more infos in this link: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this up @henke . I am going to try it now.

Comment: I just confirmed this works. @Henke Thank you very much for taking the time to write this solution up. It fixed my problem and I hope it fixes other peoples issues too.

Comment: that's great to hear!

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Now how to connect from the on prem side to the service IP range :)? a static route doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: @VincentGerris I have a internal load balancer set up in a static internal IP address. That way I configure the devices on the VPN, to access this static IP load balancer that balances the load between your services. Don't know if that would solve it for you

Comment: Also, one improvement I would like to make, but I don't know how, was to be able to have public DNS records pointing to this internal static IP, but I couldn't manage it. If you have any idea about that please let me know as well :)

Comment: hi @Henke thanks for that tip, I'm still trying to fix routing, but that internal load balancer is a great idea. Regarding DNS, I think you can use kube-dns and/or run a local bind server to resolve names, or populate the /etc/hosts file with perhaps a DaemonSet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to start with some terminologies of IP addresses in GKE.

**Network namespace**: Based on the [MAN page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html), a network namespace is logically another copy of the network stack, with its own routes, firewall rules, and network devices. This network namespace connects the node's physical network interface with the Pod. This network namespace is also connected to a Linux bridge allowing communication among pods on the same node and outside communication.

**Pod IP:**  IP address assigned to a Pod and configurable during the Cluster creation within *Pod Address Range* option. GKE assign this IP to the virtual network interface in the Pod's network namespace and routed to the node's physical network interface, such as eth0.

**Node IP:** IP address assigned to the physical network interface of a Node as `eth0`. This Node IP is configured on the network namespace to communicate with the pods.

**Cluster IP:** IP address assigned and stable for the lifetime of the service. Using the network namespace to allow communication between nodes and external network.

Here's the source of my information; [GKE Network Overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#services) where I also found this note:

> Warning: Do not manually make changes to nodes because they are overridden by GKE, and your cluster may not function correctly. The only reason to access a node directly is to debug problems with your configuration.

---

Then if you looking to establish communication between your GKE cluster and another network, I would suggest the different services:

**External Load Balancers** manage traffic coming from outside the cluster and outside your Google Cloud Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network. They use forwarding rules associated with the Google Cloud network to route traffic to a Kubernetes node.

**Internal Load Balancers** manage traffic coming from within the same VPC network. Like external load balancers, they use forwarding rules associated with the Google Cloud network to route traffic to a Kubernetes node.

**HTTP(S) Load Balancers** are specialized external load balancers used for HTTP(S) traffic. They use an Ingress resource rather than a forwarding rule to route traffic to a Kubernetes node.

You can find more details on the different services in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#outside-cluster).

In big picture, a pod cannot communicate directly with external resource.
You should use a service and expose the pod to the service.

Comment: "In big picture, a pod cannot communicate directly with external resource. You should use a service and expose the pod to the service.", but the problem is I don't want to route traffic to a pod, that is already solved.


The problem is routing traffic from the pod to another computer in another network. Hope I made it clearer. 

Thanks for helping me, but I just can't seem to explain my problem into words.

Comment: I will need more context to be able to advise you properly. I got that you have a GKE cluster and you trying to reach another network. Tell me more about this network, this is another VPC on GCP? On-Premise? Random devices on internet?

Comment: I have a VPN tunnel using Google Cloud VPN that connects some devices that I own to the Google Cloud VPC network. Those devices are reachable through this tunnel from the nodes I deploy on GCP that are on this VPC network. But the pods running inside those nodes, for some reason can't access these devices, i.e. the flux coming from the pods to the devices(reachable through the VPN tunnel).

Comment: now with this new vocabulary, I think I've found something similar to my issue? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/6545

Comment: As reference, pdecat seems have found the solution: [link 1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/6545#issuecomment-362539874)

As he mentioned, here is some more information about IP masquerade: [link 2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent)

Comment: @Henke Can you post your solution? Im running into the same issue with my GKE/AWS communication over GlobalProtect VPN...

Comment: @tdensmore, sure!! sorry about that, I hate when people solve the question and don't put the solution. But I just didn't realize hahaha

Comment: @tdensmore I've written an answer, check it out!