# Why is communication from GKE to a private ip in GCP not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have what I think is a reasonably straightforward setup in Google Cloud - A GKE cluster, a Cloud SQL instance, and a "Click-To-Deploy" Kafka VM instance.

All of the resources are in the same VPC, with firewall rules to allow all traffic to the internal VPC CIDR blocks.

The pods in the GKE cluster have no problem accessing the Cloud SQL instance via its private IP address.  But they can't seem to access the Kafka instance via its private IP address:

```
# kafkacat -L -b 10.1.100.2
% ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Broker transport failure
```

I've launched another VM manually into the VPC, and it has no problem connecting to the Kafka instance:

```
# kafkacat -L -b 10.1.100.2
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: 10.1.100.2:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 0 at ....us-east1-b.c.....internal:9092
 1 topics:
  topic "notifications" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 0, replicas: 0, isrs: 0
```

I can't seem to see any real difference in the networking between the containers in GKE and the manually launched VM, especially since both can access the Cloud SQL instance at 10.10.0.3.

Where do I go looking for what's blocking the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the error is relate to the [network](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/169), 
however if you are using gke on the same VPC network, you will ensure to [configure](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) properly the [Internal Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#int-lb), also I saw that this product or feature is BETA version, this means that it is not yet guaranteed to work as expected, another suggestion is that you ensure that you are not using any [policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy), that maybe block the connection, I found the next [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207115/egress-traffic-from-gke-pod-through-vpn) on the community that maybe help you to solve it

Comment: This isn't quite right, but led me down some promising paths, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me what I needed: https://serverfault.com/a/924317

The networking rules in GCP still seem wonky to me coming from a long time working with AWS.  I had rules that allowed anything in the VPC CIDR blocks to contact anything else in those same CIDR blocks, but that wasn't enough.  Explicitly adding the worker nodes subnet as a source for a new rule opened it up.