# NAT Pod IP to Node IP on GKE GCP or alternative solutions?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, networking, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

Here's my problem. My GKE GCP node IP addresses have access to an on premise network using ipsec/vpn and on premise firewall rules but my pod IP addresses do not. I want my traffic going from pods to use one of the acceptable node source IP addresses. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [IP Masquerarding](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ip-masquerade-agent?hl=en) and how to [edit the IP Masquerade agent](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent)

*IP masquerading is a form of source network address translation (SNAT) used to perform many-to-one IP address translations. GKE can use IP masquerading to change the source IP addresses of packets sent from Pods. When IP masquerading applies to a packet emitted by a Pod, GKE changes the packet's source address from the Pod IP to the underlying node's IP address. Masquerading a packet's source is useful when a recipient is configured to receive packets only from the cluster's node IP addresses.*

Please see this post that discusses [Egress traffic from GKE Pod through VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207115/egress-traffic-from-gke-pod-through-vpn)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I read IP masquerading  will not work for traffic to route to private address range. My destination address is a private IP connected via IPSEC/VPN. In that case what else can I use? Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067562/nat-pod-ip-to-node-ip-on-gke-gcp-or-alternative-solutions/76068313#comment134164214_76068313) discusses communication from pod to a network that is connected via VPN. So its also trying to communicate to a remote network with a Private IP

Answer (score 0):

When packets are sent to private network within VPC (or onprem connected via VPN), your cluster does not masquerade IP address sources and preserves source Pod IP addresses.
To change this behaviour update the `ip-masq-agent` config map and under `nonMasqueradeCIDRs` and remove your onprem subnet range.
Now when the packets are send to those IP address destination, cluster will masquerade IP address and use the Node IP address

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with GKE VPC + VPN, and Nat Cloud router

The VPN [requires](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#gcloud_1) ip-masq-agent scope configs for the private IPs.

Cloud Nat [requires](https://devopstales.github.io/cloud/gke-egress/) ip-masq-agent scope configs for the Public IPs.

Using both types of setups together breaks the VPN availablilty as it egresses because of the 0.0.0.0 overlay.

My solution, Add the private scopes, then populate the public networks scopes so only those 2 privates and all real public IP's are masqueraded.

```
  config: |
    nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
    - 10.40.91.0/24 # Private Scope
    - 10.0.164.0/20 # Private Scope
    - 1.0.0.0/8 # Public Scopes
    - 2.0.0.0/7
    - 4.0.0.0/6
    - 8.0.0.0/7
    - 11.0.0.0/8
    - 12.0.0.0/6
    - 16.0.0.0/4
    - 32.0.0.0/3
    - 64.0.0.0/3
    - 96.0.0.0/6
    - 128.0.0.0/2
    - 192.0.0.0/10
    - 192.64.0.0/11
    - 192.96.0.0/12
    - 192.112.0.0/13
    - 192.120.0.0/14
    - 192.124.0.0/15
    - 192.126.0.0/16
    - 192.128.0.0/9
    - 194.0.0.0/7
    - 196.0.0.0/6
    - 200.0.0.0/5
    - 208.0.0.0/4
  masqLinkLocal: true
  resyncInterval: 60s
```